# Computing differences of column entries

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a textfile with:

```
1 100
2 80
3 70
4 64
```

Now I need another file that contains the first column equal to above and the second column should be the difference of to consecutive values of the above file, i.e.:

```
1 20
2 10
3 6
```

What is the most elegant/easy way to accomplish this with unix commands?
What changes if I do not need a second file, but just have a third column in the original file with the desired differences.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For calculations `awk` is more suitable

```
awk 'NR!=1{print a,b-$2};{a=$1;b=$2}'
```

If you'd like have a third column with difference just add it:

```
awk 'NR!=1{print a,b,b-$2};{a=$1;b=$2}'
```